How to solve error by loading solution in Visual Studio in Xamarin Forms
I wanted to change start Icon in my project but when I changed png file, a stubborn error occurs. I tried to clean, unload, reload nothing worked.
Error

Error invalid file path'C:\Users\PC\source\repos\SWD_Trening\SWD_Trening\SWD_Trening.Android\obj\Debug\130\res\mainactivity.cs'. SWD_Trening.Android


Try to remove it from your project. And then delete the bin/obj folders. Finally, test it again after the cleaning.
